# Converting PDF to PNG changes fontsize

Tags: pdftex, fontsize, convert

I am writing an python-based OpenGL application that will present some text and math on the screen. These textual elements will be presented in the form of texturized quads. However, I am having trouble with the font sizes in the textures: they are larger than they should eventually be.

In order to generate the text and math texture images that will be mapped on those quads, I am doing the following:

1. I generate a `pdf` file from the latex source with `pdflatex`. The
   command used at this step is: `$ pdflatex sample.tex`
2. I generate a `png` image file from the `pdf` with Imagemagick's `convert`. That's the current command line used at this step: `$ convert -set
   units PixelsPerInch -density 112 sample.pdf -quality 100 sample.png`

The `png` file is then generated, and I could successfully map it on the quads. However, I've noticed that the font size of the `png` file does not match that of the `pdf`. In order to check it, I've rendered the same sample string on: a pdf (with `pdflatex`); a Libreoffice document; and on a `png` image file (generated with `convert` applied over the `pdf`). That's what I have got:

[image]

The topmost sentence was extracted from the `pdf`. The sentence in the middle was generated by Libreoffice. The sentence at the bottom (the larger one) was extracted from the `png` file generated from the `pdf` with `convert`. For the two first samples I've used a `10pt` Computer Modern font.

The results from `pdf` and Libreoffice are almost identical (the Libreoffice is actually a little bit shorter). I was expecting to get something very similar with the `png` file (the `-density` option of `convert` was set to 112 to match that of my computer screen). However, that string is much larger than the other two.

My questions are: Is it possible to convert a `pdf` file into a `png` such that the font-size is kept identical? If yes, how?

Below is the Latex sample file I've used for the test above:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{white}
This is a test... 0123456789
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you know the PNG is not just showing up on screen at a bigger size? If you mean that the font size has increased relative to the size of the page, then that almost defeats the point of PDF (Portable Document Format), so I doubt that's happening. If you mean that the entire page is being displayed at a bigger size (and not just the text on the page), then that's a different question. Which is it?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I think that the PNG is not showing up at a bigger size because when I open it in the image viewer (I am using gwenview for this) I set the zoom factor to 100% (this way I believe to keep a 1=1 match between image and screen pixels... I've done the same for the PDF and Libreoffice... set the zoom to 100%).

Comment: (Welcome to TeX.SE BTW.) Just a hunch: try 96dpi instead of 112. (Not sure where the 112 comes from exactly, but 96 is a kind of standard assumed by many software applications.) In any case, this does not seem a problem with the TeX side of things (I'm assuming that when you open the PDF in your PDF viewer, things are fine), but with Imagemagick (the `convert` program).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I have jut made a quick test: I've set density to 96 dpi in convert, and now the fonts on the png file seem to have the same size as those on the pdf (both viewed at 100% zoom). I have then run the command "$ xrdb -query", and verified that Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) sets the dpi to 96 (Xft.dpi: 96), although the actual dpi is ~112. I think the problem is that the dpi seems to be fixed, despite the actual density of the display. I will not include it as an answer because I am not expert on this, and I may be totally wrong.

Comment: The PNG doesn't have any fonts and so doesn't have any font size. It is just a picture with no font information whatsoever. I don't really understand what you want to do here. What will happen when somebody opens the file on a screen with a different DPI? If it worked as you want, it would then be an entirely different size, so how would you be keeping it consistent? Even if it worked on your screen, it would fail elsewhere, surely?

Comment: @ChristianPagot It is a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: Basically repeating what cfr says, the statement that the font size got changed makes only sense when the size relative to some other element, say a box, is changed.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I was writing the last cooment and I did not see your answer.. That's it! It seems that 96dpi is a standard. Now everything seems to be working. Thank you (repost your comment above as an answer ... I will accept it!).

Comment: @ChristianPagot If you send me the results, it won't display the same way because my DPI is NOT set to 96.

Comment: @cfr I understand your point. However, my application regenerate all png files everytime the application is run, thus I can extract the current dpi and sample the pdf files accordingly.

Comment: @cfr I think the problem was that I was using the actual dpi of my screen (I was calculating it.. from the physical dimensions of the screen - inches - and its resolution in pixels). However, it seems that document writers and viewers do not use that dpi information, but the dpi information stored into the OS (in my case, it is 96dpi). But this is just a guess.. as I've said before, I am not an expert.

Comment: @ChristianPagot And how do you plan to extract that information exactly?

Comment: @cfr Assuming that from now on I will use the dpi info from the OS, I might use the command that I've shown before: "$ xrdb -query" and then use regex to extract the dpi value (at least in Linux).

Comment: @ChristianPagot https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=231188 You need to make it configurable at least, because what you expect probably ain't so. On Linux, at least.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72945/discussion-between-cfr-and-christian-pagot).